# Is there a way to set omitempty and cdata tag at the same time when doing xml.Marshal()?

Tags: xml, go

From a [Chinese source](https://segmentfault.com/q/1010000008231680), to generate a cdata output when using `xml.Marshal()`, I may:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type TextMsg struct {
    XMLName      xml.Name `xml:"xml"`
    ToUserName   CDATA
    FromUserName CDATA
    CreateTime   int64
    MsgType      CDATA
    Content      CDATA
}

type CDATA struct {
    Text string `xml:",cdata"`
}

func main() {
    msg := TextMsg{
        ToUserName:   CDATA{"userId"},
        FromUserName: CDATA{"appId"},
        CreateTime:   time.Now().Unix(),
        MsgType:      CDATA{"text"},
        Content:      CDATA{"some message like <hello>"}}

    b, _ := xml.MarshalIndent(msg, "", "    ")
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}
```

However, if I want to add `.omitempty` tag at the same time, I have tried changing the `TextMsg` struct to:

```
type TextMsg struct {
    XMLName      xml.Name `xml:"xml"`
    ToUserName   CDATA `xml:",omitempty"`
    FromUserName CDATA `xml:",omitempty"`
    CreateTime   int64 `xml:",omitempty"`
    MsgType      CDATA `xml:",omitempty"`
    Content      CDATA `xml:",omitempty"`
}
```

and changing the `main()` to:

```
var msg TextMsg
msg.ToUserName = CDATA{"userId"},
msg.FromUserName: CDATA{"appId"},
msg.CreateTime:   time.Now().Unix(),

b, _ := xml.MarshalIndent(msg, "", "    ")
```

The empty `MsgType` and `Content` are not omitted. May I know what is the correct way to set `omitempty` with `cdata` tag together?

Comment: It's not omitted, because it's not empty. `CDATA` is a struct, which can never be "empty". If you want to make it emptyable, you may want to use `*CDATA` (a pointer to type `CDATA`) which can be `nil`, which is considered empty. This behavior is covered in [the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Marshal) for the `omitempty` tag.

Comment: If I am using `*CDATA` as type, do I have a way to asign value to it without declaring a variable?

Comment: You mean like `msg.ToUserName = &CDATA{"userId"}` ?